# How to get data from AskDialog back to activity

Tags: android, dialog

I have one activity1 with listview and after click on one item of list it shows own askDialog with 2 optiones(Buttons). I need to get back which one i clicked to open another activity from my activity1 with list. How can i do that?
My AskDialog:

```
public class AskDialog extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;

private Button edit;
private Button delete;
private int position;
private boolean tariff;

public AskDialog(Activity a,int position,boolean tariff) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
    this.position = position;
    this.tariff = tariff;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.ask_dialog);
    edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
    if(tariff){
        edit.setText("Zobrazit záznam");
    }
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    edit.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.editBtn:

            break;
        case R.id.deleteBtn:
dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

This is where i call that dialog:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                        long id) {
                    positionOfTAriff = position;
AskDialog askDialog = new AskDialog(MyCommonListActivity.this,position,false);
askDialog.show();
```

Or is there any odher dialog i should use for that?

Comment: Cannot start the AskDialog the next activity? You could give its constructor the necessary parameters. Otherwise implement a Callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";

// use a default value using new Date()
long l = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

To edit and save preferences

```
Date dt = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).apply();
```

You can commit preferences in AsdkDialog and read in your activity or fragment.

Comment: Hello, you try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approaches

1. Create interface, implement your activity/fragment with created interface, pass its reference to your dialog and initialize in dialog, than in `onDestroy()` call your interface method using reference saved in your dialog
2. Update your dialog to DialogFragment, before calling `dialog.show();` call `dialog.setTargetFragment(TargetFragment, RequestCode);` and implement `onActivityResult` in your `Fragment` as well as in your `Activity`, and before destroying your dialog call `getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(RequestCode,        Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a Callback parameter to the constructor of your dialog.

```
Callback myCallback;
public AskDialog(Activity a, int position, Callback myCallback, boolean tariff) {
super(a);
this.c = a;
this.position = position;  
this.tariff = tariff;
this.myCallback = myCallback;
}
```

Change onClick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.editBtn:
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("choice", "edit");
            bundle.putInt("position", position);

            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.setData(bundle);
            myCallback.handleMessage(msg);

            dismiss();
       }
    break;
    case R.id.deleteBtn:
       {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("choice", "delete");
            bundle.putInt("position", position);

            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.setData(bundle);
            myCallback.handleMessage(msg);

            dismiss();
       }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }  
}
```

Where you call the dialog you make the callback handler:

```
 Callback theCallback = new Callback() {
    // @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // super.handleMessage(msg);
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        String choice = bundle.getString("choice");
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, choice + "\nposition: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
        return true;
    }
};
```

And you call the dialog with:

```
 new AskDialog( MainActivity.this, position, theCallback, false).show();
```

Comment: What should I import to be able to use this Callback?

Comment: Isn't your IDE suggestion some imports when you have the mouse above that word? `import android.os.Handler.Callback;`.